# Docker In Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, docker-in-docker

I am using a third party library that creates sibling docker containers via:

```
docker run -d /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

I am trying to create a Kubernetes deployment out of the above container, but currently getting:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

This is expected because I am not declaring `/var/run/docker.sock` as a volume in the deployment yaml.

The problem is I don't know how to do this. Is it possible to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` as a volume in a deployment yaml?

If not, what is the best approach to run docker sibling-containers from within a Kubernetes deployment/pod?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unverified as it sounds brittle to me to start a container outside of k8s supervision, but you should be able to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` with a [hostPath volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).

Example variation from the documentation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      name: docker-sock-volume
  volumes:
  - name: docker-sock-volume
    hostPath:
      # location on host
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
      # this field is optional
      type: File
```

I think a simple mount should be enough to allow communication from docker client within the container to docker daemon on host but in case you get a write permission error it means you need to run your container as privileged container
 using a [securityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container) object like such (just an extract from above to show the addition, values taken from [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#securitycontext-v1-core)):

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    name: test-container
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Yeah it is a third party tool so it is not ideal. But I at least want the main container in Kubernetes to make it more reliable. The container ramps up temporary containers with browsers for automation UI testing, then the browser container is destroyed.

Comment: @rys yes, that was a case I had think of, you may still run into problems if the node load goes too high as k8s may move your 'launcher' container. But I assume the failure of the test suite is something acceptable in this case

Comment: This is no longer supported https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/docker-containerd. You can use sidecar dind or k8s jobs. I have the exact same problem and honestly the community has been very hostile when I've asked about this lol here's me trying to get an answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/yrf215/eks_ive_been_struggling_with_the_upcoming_removal/

Comment: The question was specifically about a k8s using docker as container runtime. Kubernetes has moved away from only docker to a CRI interface so obviously it won't apply to managed k8s not using docker as CRI.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a working solution (I use it myself), there some drawbacks for running Docker in a Kubernetes pod by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock`

Mostly the fact you are working with Docker containers outside the control of Kubernetes.

Another suggested solution I found is using a **side-car** container in your pod. See [A Case for Docker-in-Docker on Kubernetes](https://applatix.com/case-docker-docker-kubernetes-part/). There are two parts to it where the proposed solution is in [part 2](https://applatix.com/case-docker-docker-kubernetes-part-2/).

I hope this helps.